# Date values in URL get corrupted for MVC GET request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following code to send a get request to my controller when I detect a client side change to the Telerik MVC DatePicker.

```
function RaceDate_onChange() {
    var pickedDate = $(this).data('tDatePicker').value();
    $.get("/RaceCard/Details?year=" + pickedDate.getYear() + "&month=" + pickedDate.getMonth() + "&day=" + pickedDate.getDay());
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int year, int month, int day)
```

I am building the URL with d/m/y values of 2011/7/10, yet the d/m/y values arriving at my controller action are 111/6/0.  If I inspect the HttpContext.Request object at a breakpoint in my controller, I observe these suspicious values:

```
Url: {http://localhost:59927/RaceCard/Details?year=111&month=6&day=0}
UrlReferrer: {http://localhost:59927/RaceCard/Details?year=2011&month=7&day=10}
```

I think this is purely a JS issue, but I have no clue where to start, except here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) returns the number of years since 1900. Use [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.

[getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is zero based so January = 0, February = 1

[getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns a zero based integer representation of the day of the week e.g. Sunday = 0, Monday = 1.  You want to use [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) which returns the date of the month

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDay());
alert(d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate());
```

Comment: Thanks, now just to determine why my day is still 0.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot you were using `getDay()`, you should be using `getDate()` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Nothing as intuitive as legacy JavaScript objects.